# Apache flink dataset

Tags: apache-flink

I have DataSet data object which will have result set of 50 columns data. Now I want to filter the result set DataSet filteredData which should have only 2 columns data. How to do this Apache Flink java?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

val intNumbers: DataSet[Int] = // [...]
val naturalNumbers = intNumbers.filter { row1,row2 }